# Why does Windows have to reinstall P&P drivers when you switch USB ports?

Tags: windows-7, windows, usb, drivers

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Why does my computer go “New USB device” every time I plug one into a different port?](https://superuser.com/questions/29021/why-does-my-computer-go-new-usb-device-every-time-i-plug-one-into-a-different)

I've noticed that the first time I plug in a new Plug & Play USB device, e.g. a mouse, Windows takes a few seconds to install the drivers for the device.  If I unplug and reinsert the USB plug into the same port, it doesn't need to do that again.  But if I insert the plug into a different USB port, Windows goes through the whole driver installation process again.

Why is that?

Comment: Because the archaic driver system tied the device to the port it was installed onto....

Comment: @billc.cn - citation/references?