# Why does Windows XP ask for installation of new USB device every time?

Tags: windows-xp, usb, drivers

> Acer Veriton T661 Windows XP Service Pack 3 32bit 2GB RAM 320GB HDD

Problem: Each time you plug in a new USB device, it will ask you to install it with the Windows driver installer Wizard. Once you have gone through the whole install process, using automatic driver find and installation, the USB works. This is tiresome, as you need to install a new USB device every time.

On all other XP machines I came across this just doesn't happen. You plug in your standard USB device (mouse, external drive, keyboard) and it picks it up, installs it automatically and then you can use it. **Why** on earth would this machine ask for USB installation with every device you plug in ? It should be a simple "plug and play" for these standard devices !

What I've done is I've uninstalled ALL USB drivers, rebooted and Windows re-installed them. Then I got the new chipset drivers and installed them. I've also checked the Universal Plug and Play service and the Plug and Play service. I also looked at the old thread [Why does my computer go “New USB device” every time I plug one into a different port?](https://superuser.com/questions/29021/why-does-my-computer-go-new-usb-device-every-time-i-plug-one-into-a-different) and many other threads on Google that I could find.

When I get back this unit I will try :

1.) Delete the infache.1 file found in C:\Windows\inf

2.) Update the machine BIOS (doubt that this will make any difference)

3.) REG ADD hklm\system\currentcontrolset\services\USB /v DisableSelectiveSuspend /t REG_DWORD /d 1

Comment: We can't help you unless you have access to the machine.  Have you thought about upgrading to at least Windows 7?

Comment: I will get access to it during the day/week and then I'll see. No, upgrading is not an option. There needs to be a fix ; registry or something.

Comment: Without knowing what about the registery has been changed a registry fix is hard to come up with.  Can you restore the default image for the system.

Comment: Yes I can try to restore... just hope the client has some working restore points on there. The idea is that windows should have a key in the registry that contains the default USB settings in addition to the ones that it has already saved. The drivers are always the same, so when changing them or updating, it will reference to the same files.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the OP went off to try and verify some things and never came back to update the question.

Comment: Apologies :D I was not able to solve this issue. I think (if I recall correctly) we re-installed the system and all was well again.