# Prevent searching for drivers when there is already one installed

Tags: windows-7, windows, usb, drivers

Is there a way to, on Windows 7, prevent Windows for checking for updated drivers every time a device is plugged into the *same* USB port? I know I can set it so that it doesn't check at all, but I'm trying to figure out if there is a way to make it so that, once the driver is initially installed, it stops checking every time.

Some info about the particulars involved: I'm trying to speed up the device detection of a wireless transmitter connected via the USB port. As of right now, after being plugged in the computer takes some time (a few seconds to a minute) to detect the device. I have read that part of this delay is caused by Windows searching for updated drivers.

I'm running Windows 7 on an Acer laptop with an Intel I5.

Comment: You are plugging the device into the same USB port each time correct?  Here is a [related](http://superuser.com/questions/29021/why-does-my-computer-go-new-usb-device-every-time-i-plug-one-into-a-different) question which explains the behavior you have witnessed.

Comment: When you plug it in does Windows show you the little USB task icon, and tell you it's searching for and loading drivers? If not, then that's probably not what's happening.

Comment: Yes, generally when I notice the slowness it does give me the USB task icon.
Also, I am plugging the device into the same USB port each time.

Comment: Irrespective of the side effects if you just want the computer to stop looking/updating drivers, you can refer to this https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/2500967