# USB Port not working for only one device

Tags: usb, drivers

There's a problem I always met in my life and in my jobs, and never found an answer :

Sometimes, a device stops working on one or more USB ports while working on the other ports. But all the other devices work well on these USB ports.

It's just like a USB port don't want anymore to recognize a specific device. It feels like the device's driver install on each USB port, crashing sometimes and making the device unusable on this particular port.

For example, you have a device that works on port A. Some day, it stops to works on this port. You connect it on port B and the device works again, but still not on port A. But any other device works fine on port A.

Tried to scan for hardware changes on devmgmt.msc and tried to reboot.
Nothing works.

I got this problem with PS4 controller, using DS4Windows.
Got it too with a barcode scanner.

Do someone else already met this issue and know how to fix this ?

I did find this question: [Why does my computer go "New USB device" every time I plug one into a different port?](https://superuser.com/questions/29021/why-does-my-computer-go-new-usb-device-every-time-i-plug-one-into-a-different)

It seems Windows can link the driver from port to port, but he needs the devices to have a serial number.

If it's not the case, he'll install the driver every time you connect it to a new port. That could explain why it crashes on only one port sometimes.

But the question is, how to avoid that, and how to fix it once the port/driver pair goes wild?

Comment: Windows has always had what I consider to be 'odd' behaviour regarding ports & drivers. It will 'install' a new driver for each & every port you plug something into. One of these instances has failed, but trying to pick it out is not a simple task, especially if it's a 'standard' device driver. [I never did figure out how to do it, but just for info]

Comment: @DoT - Sounds like you should [edit] your question instead of having relevant information in a comment

Comment: The purpose of my first comment was to inform you that an edit function existed.

Comment: @Ramhound Ok, thanks.